# Use preg_math with special characters

Tags: php

I have a question. I have one text like this `<b> Â Â Â  brat stergator carlig </b>` and I want to remove `Â` but I want to retain `<b>` tag.

Personally I thought at math_preg but I don't know how. A little help it will be great. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for regex. Simply use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). Make sure to use the proper encoding for your PHP file (should be UTF-8), otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %[].()%&-]/s', '', $var);  is correct.  I can't use  str_replace() because I don't have Â . This sign is generated when I made the insertion in my database